# Unity3D IOS Basic License, link from Lite to Full version?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, store

Let's say I have 2 version of my game, one Lite and the Full one, I want to put a button in the Lite one to open the AppStore directly to the Full version

I've read about the native plugin option but AFAIK that only works with the Pro Version of Unity and well, I don't have budget right now for it

Are there alternatives to do the same with the IOS Basic License?

Thank you!

Jorge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [Application.OpenURL](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application.OpenURL.html) and then send them to a link that will open the app store.

```
Application.OpenURL("http://itunes.com/apps/YOURAPPNAME");
```

(You might be able to replace `http` with `itms` or `itms-apps`).